# insert month and year into a label caption

Tags: vba, formatting, caption

How do i change the format current month and year at the end of a caption. I have tried using a cell on the worksheet and then formatting it to `mmmm yy` however when i tell the caption to update on the user-form initialize sequence it comes through in a short date format. Below is the code as it stands.

```
 MobilePricing.Label313.Caption = "Daisy Group Vodafone Mobile Pricing Tool " & _
 Worksheets("Calculator").Range("V2")
```

Any advise on how i can change the format of the date to `mmmm yy` would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `V2` is holding a date value.

```
MobilePricing.Label313.Caption = "Daisy Group Vodafone Mobile Pricing Tool " & _
 Format(Worksheets("Calculator").Range("V2"),"mmmm yy")
```

I have used the `Format` function to convert the date into the format you want.

Comment: Works a charm thank you. I knew it was going to be simple.